# Arranging top of columns in legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, legend, layouts

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1 Standard License.

I have a legend item that I would like to split across two columns. Below is the output.

[image]

What I would like to have is the top of the second column align with the top of the first column.  So that boxes A and C are aligned.

My current settings are:

[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

Converting the legend to graphics is not an option for me.

Comment: Perhaps split your Layer into two using definition queries so that you can have two items in your legend - one with and one without a heading - the latter starting lower.

Comment: This is one of the main deficiencies of legend object in ArcMap, you cannot set a break-point for columns and even if you set manually, it will not align with the layer name. In the past, I did what @PolyGeo advised with two legends but as you know you will lose, most precious, dynamic behaviour of the legend object.

Comment: if it's the only item, you can turn off the layer name option, and use the legend title text instead.

Comment: @TDavis, This actually worked for me because it was the only layer in this legend.  If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the layer name from the legend (uncheck the 'show layer name' box in the properties) and edit the legend title from the default 'Legend' to the name of the layer, and the column tops will line up.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps split your Layer into two using definition queries so that you can have two items in your legend - one with and one without a heading - the latter starting lower.